# How to create Azure Batch Job with AutoPool and Managed Identity

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-batch

CAVEAT: THIS APP USES .NET FRAMEWORK 4.7

I am familiar with the need to use `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Batch` for creating batch pools with managed identity: see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/managed-identity-pools

We have code that creates a job with `Microsoft.Azure.Batch` library and also creates an `AutoPool` see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/nodes-and-pools#autopools

```
var poolInformation = new PoolInformation
{
    AutoPoolSpecification = new AutoPoolSpecification
    {
        AutoPoolIdPrefix = this.autoPoolIdPrefix,
        PoolLifetimeOption = PoolLifetimeOption.Job,
        PoolSpecification = GetPoolSpec(),
        KeepAlive = false
    }
};
job = batchClient.JobOperations.CreateJob(autoPoolJobId, poolInformation);
```

is there a way to create this job with a batch pool that uses a managed identity?